# Save & Close button javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm creating a form where user can select between 3 types of predefined letters and a custom one by selecting from a drop down menu.
I have a javascript function that opens a popup window when 'custom letter' is chosen, so far so good.
What i want is on the popup window to have a text area where user can write whatever he wants and finally press a button which saves that text written and close that popup.... is it possible?

I'm using php and javascript, but i presume some ajax will be needed here.....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just embed the textarea and the button in a form that POSTs to the PHP script that handles the saving.

```
<form action="save_stuff.php" method="post" onsubmit="window.close();">
    <textarea name="letter" cols="50" rows="50"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save & Exit" />
</form>
```

Comment: But that won't close the new window

Comment: If you choose to to do it in a non-AJAX method like this, you would have to return Javascript code (`window.close()`) within a script tag to close the window.

Comment: close the form in the save_stuff.php

Comment: Use `onsubmit='window.close();'` to close the window when the button is clicked

Comment: Added PitaJ's suggestion to the original answer.

Comment: Closing from save_stuff.php seems like a better idea. That way if something goes wrong with the submission, the page won't be closed and the user can try again, or at least get their text out.

Comment: i created the form pointing to the same page. Did the save routine and a new query to see if it's saved ok, if so i've placed the window.close button. Many thanks for the aproach.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the popup, you would have a form that submits the contents of the text area to your server (which will save it to your DB). You could use AJAX to do this. When the ajax call returns successfully, close the popup.

Comment: yes, that's the idea, save that text area into a mysql database. Any idea on how to do so? i'm null using ajax......

Comment: I would recommend you use jQuery to do cross-browser compliant AJAX requests: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Make sure you clean the text or you could be hacked.